# Entering Chinese Character in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have got some Characters in Chinese,While entering those characters in SQLite database they get converted into � symbol. Is there a way to persist those characters after they are inserted into SQLite.

Comment: sqlite supports unicode directly. What the question boild down is how you are inserting the data and how you are displaying it - it's easy to mess up the encoding there.

Comment: Are you using the Windows Command Prompt, or anything else?

Comment: laalto-We are inserting the data using Ado.net,It is a simple insertion in SQLite

Comment: CL-We are inserting it using Ado.net and displaying the data in slickgrid